# DCPError in CVXPY when multiplying a scalar parameter with a scalar variable

Tags: python, cvxpy

When a scalar parameter is multiplied with a variable, CVXPY outputs the DCPError

`DCPError: Product of two non-constant expressions is not DCP.`

but
`problem.is_dcp()` returns True

Here is the code to reproduce this error.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

lam = cp.Variable(pos=True)

lam_min = cp.Parameter(pos=True, value=1.0)
g = cp.Parameter(pos=True, value=1.0)

constraints = [
    lam >= lam_min,
]

objective_fn = g*lam

problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(objective_fn), constraints)
print(problem.is_dcp()) 
problem.solve()
```

It is solving the following simple linear problem in one dimension

```
minimize     g*lam
subject to   lam >= lam_min
```

The question is

```
Why does the solver say that the problem is DCP and at the same time output a DCPError?
```

**Update following sascha'a comment**

I was running the script from Spyder on Ubuntu. Following sascha's comment that the snippet was generating no error for them, I ran the script inside a terminal and indeed there is no error!

```
Why is there this error when the script is run within Spyder but not in a terminal?
```

Comment: This snippet does not show any error here.

Comment: I am using CVXPY version 1.1.15 and Python 3.7 on Ubuntu. and it shows the said DCPError

Comment: I forgot to add that I am running the script from within Spyder. Since you mentioned that you did not get an error, I ran the same script inside a terminal. And this time there is no error! Would you know why the exception occurs inside Spyder?

Comment: No. But i wouldn't be surprised, if you would be using a completely different (probably broken) version of cvxpy without knowing it. Check `import cvxpy` + `print(cvxpy.__version__)` within your spyder-based code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I checked the versions in spyder and in terminal. Both are using the same version cvxpy 1.1.15